# Can I change the tint color and font attributes of a label for just a specific part?

Tags: xamarin.ios, label

I need to format a string in a label so that just the words that I want are displayed in a different color and with a different font attribute. I dont know if its possible to do so. I know I can change it in a TextView but im not sure about a label and havent found anything in my google search.

Can someone tell me whether it is possible? And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@dannyc/custom-xamarin-ios-uilabel-attributes-using-xamarin-workbooks-14f3dba98fdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `AttributedText` property of **UILable** to achieve that.

The **[NSAttributedString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsattributedstring?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)** type represents a string that has a series of attributes applied uniformly.

[image]

The companion **[NSMutableAttributedString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsmutableattributedstring?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)** type can be used to create attributed strings that have overlapping attributes and whose contents can be modified after creation.

[image]

The sample code of `NSAttributedString`:

```
var label0 = new UILabel(new CGRect(20, 100, 400, 50));
View.AddSubview(label1);
var text = new NSAttributedString(
"Here is the test for NSAttributedString.",
font: UIFont.FromName("HoeflerText-Regular", 24.0f),
foregroundColor: UIColor.Red,
strokeWidth: 4
);
label0.AttributedText = text;
```

The sample code of `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
var label1 = new UILabel(new CGRect(20, 200, 400, 50));
View.AddSubview(label);
var mutableStr = new NSMutableAttributedString("Here is the test for NSMutableAttributedString.");
var range = mutableStr.MutableString.LocalizedStandardRangeOfString(new NSString("test"));
mutableStr.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Red, range);
mutableStr.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Font, UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(25), range);
label1.AttributedText = mutableStr;
```

The effect:

[image]